# Cannot access the html DOM inside Vue3 app instance setup function

Tags: dom, vuejs3

I am using vue3 inside html file because what I was told to do... and this is happening

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "app">
    <div id="here"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
  const { createApp } = Vue
  const x = document.getElementById('here')
  console.log('outside', x)

  createApp({ 
    setup(){
     const x = document.getElementById('here')
     console.log('inside', x)
    } 
  }).mount('#app')
 </script>
</html>
```

the result is like this.

```
outside <div ...> 
inside null
```

Could you please explain this to me? I was trying to look up the documentation but didn't know how to find with the proper keyword. maybe createApp creates separate context from the parent one so I cannot refer it inside it?

+) I tested vue3 part and it works fine. I can refer the data the returned by setup funciton inside html part.

Comment: It works. I follwed the instruction from the official documents. https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn

Comment: ok. I will upload full code snippet example.

Comment: and you were right. I skipped the const {createApp} = Vue part in my example.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say you're hitting something of a timing issue where Vue is processing the template (your `<div id="app">` element) and has temporarily removed the current DOM elements. It might help to know what you're trying to do exactly because it doesn't look like the _Vue way_

Comment: yes. you were right. maybe some timing issue. so I moved it inside the onMounted hook and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

move it inside onMounted hook.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "app">
    <div id="here"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
  const { createApp, onMounted } = Vue
  const x = document.getElementById('here')
  console.log('outside', x)

  createApp({ 
    setup(){
     const y = document.getElementById('here')
     console.log('inside', y)
     
     onMounted(() => {
      const z = document.getElementById('here')
      console.log('onMounted', z)
     })
    } 
  }).mount('#app')
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Setup occurs before the vue components create, you can refer to the code below.

```js
setup(){
  Vue.onMounted(function() {
    const x = document.getElementById('here')
    console.log('inside', x)
   })
}
```